# Sed replace only exact match

Tags: unix, sed

I wan't to replace a string like `Europe12` with `Europe12_yesturday` in a file. Without changing the `Europe12-36` strings that also exists in the file.

I tried:

```
$basename=Europe12
sed -i 's/\b$basename\b/${basename}_yesterday/g' file.txt
```

but this also changed the `Europe12-36` strings.

Answer (score 1):

Manually construct the delimiter list you want instead of using `\b`, `\W` or `\<`. `-` is not part of the word characters (alphanumericals), so that's why this also matches your other string. So try something like this, expanding the list as needed: `[-a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Require a space or end of line character:

```
sed 's/Europe12\([ ]|$\)/Europe12_yesturday\1/g' input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 times:

```
sed -e 's/Europe12/Europe12_yesturday/g' -e 's/Europe12_yesturday-36/Europe12-36/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(Europe12[[:blank:]]\)/\1_yesturday/g;s/Europe12$/&_yesturday/' YourFile
```

[[:blank:]] could be completeted with any boundary you accept also like .,;:/]) etc (be carrefull of regex meaning of this char in this case)

Answer (score 0):

It is little late to reply..
It can be achieved easily by "word boundary" notation (\<..\>)

```
sed -i 's/\<$basename\>/${basename}_yesterday/g' file.txt
```